# Overwrite Vuetify default grey dark theme

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `nuxt.js` and have installed `Vuetify` and have added a dark theme to one of my layout pages. So I have two layout pages (Light and Dark). I have mounted this to my layout to switch out the theme, so I can either use a dark theme page or a light one.

```
        mounted(){
            setTimeout(() => this.$vuetify.theme.dark = false, 0);
        }
```

When the theme switches to dark it goes a grey colour by default. I want to change this grey colour to a dark blue colour. How can I change the variables to change the base `black-gray` colour to a base dark blue color?

**I don't want to create a "Dark theme"** in the `nuxt.config.js` file. This is not what I want to do because I then have to add, `color="primary"` to my dark theme everywhere.

**I want to do is set my base colour** to dark-blue instead of black-grey and then all colours in my theme will change. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [docs for information about customizing the theme color palette](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#customizing).

The docs say that you can define this way the color definitions with colors of your choice.

This is an example plugin of the docs:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

import colors from 'vuetify/lib/util/colors'

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      dark: {
        primary: colors.blue.lighten3,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Ok, I'm looking to over write the elevation $material-dark-elevation-colors found in vuetify/src/styles/settings/_dark as these have shade of grey